# How to do a sliding transition in RubyMotion?

Tags: ios5, rubymotion

I've been looking at the different examples of loading a screen - is there a way to insert a transition screen (sliding) when the a tap is detected? Currently UIImage.imageNamed loads up the next graphic instantly - how to make it slide?

```
def viewDidLoad
  view.image = UIImage.imageNamed('welcome.png')

  view.userInteractionEnabled = true
  recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer.alloc.initWithTarget(self, action:'nextScreen')
  view.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `nextScreen` method that should do what you want. With the animation setup, the `view.image = ...` line will slide the image in from the right.

```
def nextScreen
  animation = CATransition.animation
  animation.duration = 0.5
  animation.type = KCATransitionMoveIn
  animation.subtype = KCATransitionFromRight
  view.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey:'imageTransition')
  view.image = UIImage.imageNamed('pic2.png')
end
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5057691/424300